# How to count in Rselenium by using class?

Tags: r, rselenium

```
<span class="audience-reviews__score">
<span class="star-display"><span class="star-display__filled ">
</span><span class="star-display__filled ">
</span><span class="star-display__filled ">
</span><span class="star-display__filled ">
</span><span class="star-display__empty">
</span></span></span>
```

Need advice on how to use Rselenium to count "class="star-display__filled" as 1 and class="star-display__empty" as 0.

Comment: `library(rvest); read_html(your_html) %>% html_nodes('.star-display__filled') %>% length()`

Comment: i don't think i able to use rvest, as the page is dynamic.

Comment: pull the html with the `getPageSource()` method in RSelenium, then parse with rvest